# Setting Keyframe interval on DirectShow Encoder

Tags: video, encoding, directshow, h.264, directshow.net

I have seen some strange behavior when seeking during playback on a video, I have created the video using DirectShow - the issue is on Windows 7 Only (W8/W10 works fine).

The graph is built like this:

```
Source(Webcam) -> H264 Encoder -> MP4 Mux -> File Writer
```

So I am using a H264 Encoder, however for some reason the Encoder removes all Keyframes(Sync) after the encoder Filter. Using another older H264 Encoder I can see that it sets a Keyframe(Sync) each 20 frames perfectly, and the output File from this encoder works flawlessly on all operating systems.

So I suspect the issue lies with the encoder not setting Keyframes correctly and therefor won't be able to seek correctly (however Windows 8 and 10 can figure out how to seek on the file without Keyframes correctly, just not Windows 7)

Using VLC/WMP on Windows 7 when seeking on the file the file will act strange (No video for a long while, gray pixelated video for over 10 seconds, suddenly stop of video..)

So my question is, how do I set the interval of the keyframe on an Encoding Filter in DirectShow?

Edit: Another interesting thing I found is that when I seek, this weird output is seen via the Analyzer Filter (inserted just after the decoder) during playback. [image]

Comment: Nicholas, out of curiosity what H264 encoder are you using?

Comment: @MikeDinescu I am using VisioForge H264

Comment: Since VisioForge seems to be a commercial product I'd think the best bet is to reach out to the developers and request documentation - and in case the feature is not available (or not implemented correctly) that they add/fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decision on insertion of a key frame is encoder's. It might have a setting that define GOP length and minimal frequency of key frames. It might additionally insert a key frame on scene change. It might additionally accept external requests to insert at specific point.

Generic approach is [`IAMVideoCompression::put_KeyFrameRate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376019). In the same time I would say it's encoder specific. You should check documentation for specific encoder you are using to find out how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Roman. This is a perfect answer to the question, sadly in my case IAMVideoCompression isn't supported - So I'm going to have to hope that my encoder has some way of doing it.